# Find number of solutions such that $\sum_i A_i = X$ and $\gcd(A_1,A_2....) = Y$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Find number of solutions such that $\sum_i A_i = X$ and $\gcd(A_1,A_2....) = Y$ ?

This question was asked recently in one of the programming questions, and I'm not able to figure out the approach to solve this problem.

Let's suppose, for example: $X = 12$ and $Y = 4$

So, A can be $\{4,4,4\}, \{8,4\}, \{4,8\}$ no such restriction on size of array given in the problem statement.

thanks in advance for helping! Would be more than happy to clarify the question if needed, Though the reference to the question is lost :p

Edit: Removing the upper Bound, I added just for the programmer's sake for giving the reference to X and Y that they can be large values. sorry if that caused any misinterpretation of the question.

Comment: If there are any solutions, you need $Y\mid X$ and you can reduce the question to the case $X'=X/Y, Y'=1.$

Comment: (Oh, except with the upper bound now being $\lfloor 10^9/Y\rfloor$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: right, but one of the reduced addenda shall be 1.

Comment: @GCab Not necessarily. $12+20+30=62$, with $gcd(12,20,30)=2$. Dividing by $2$, we get $6+10+15$, none of which are $1$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: oh, yes, you are right! sorry.

Comment: Without the upper limit $10^9$, it is relatively easier to do it. Relatively.

Comment: Can you suggest me that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which works without the constraints $A_i\le 10^9$.

---

Let $f(Y)$ be the number of solutions to $\sum_i A_i=X$ with $\gcd(A_i)=Y$. This can only be nonzero if $Y$ divides evenly into $X$.

Let $g(Y)$ be the number of solutions to $\sum_i A_i=X$ where each $A_i$ is a multiple of $Y$. Letting $B_i=A_i/Y$, this is the same as solving $\sum_i B_i=X/Y$, or finding the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $X/Y$, the number of which is $$g(Y)=2^{X/Y-1}.$$

Now, we can write $g(Y)$ in terms of $f(Y)$, because each $A_i$ is a multiple of $Y$ if and only if $\gcd(A_i)$ is some multiple $d$ of $Y$. Summing over all such $d$, we get
$$
g(Y)=\sum_{Y|d|X}f(d)=\sum_{d|(X/Y)} f(X/d)
$$
In the first equality, $d$ ranges over multiples of $Y$ which are also divisors of $X$. In the second, we reindex the summation via $d\gets X/d$. Let us write this slightly differently as
$$
g(X/Y)=\sum_{d|Y}f(X/d)
$$
Finally, we conclude by applying [Mobius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula):
$$
f(X/Y)=\sum_{d|Y}\mu(d)g(dX/Y)
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(Y)=\sum_{d|(X/Y)}\mu(d)g(dY)=\sum_{d|(X/Y)}\mu(d)2^{X/(dY)-1}
$$
In order to compute this quickly, you need to find the prime factorization of $X/Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $Y=1$ first, and pick an $M$ as the upper bound for the $A_i.$

Let $S(X,M)=S,$ of ways to write $X$ as a sum of positive integers bounded above by $M$, but with no $\gcd$ restriction. Let $c(X,M)=\left|S(X,M)\right|.$

Let $p_1,\dots, p_k$ be the distinct prime divisors of $X.$ Let $B_i$ be the set of elements of $S$ with all summands divisible by $p_i.$ We get, for dinstict $1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_m\leq k$ we get that $$\left|B_{i_1}\cap B_{i_2}\cap \cdots B_{i_m}\right|=c\left(\frac{X}{p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\cdots p_{i_m}},\left\lfloor\frac{M}{p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\cdots p_{i_m}}\right\rfloor\right)$$

The total can the be written, using inclusion-exclusion, as:

$$\sum_{d\mid X}\mu(d)\,\, c\left(\frac{X}{d},\left\lfloor\frac{M}{d}\right\rfloor\right)\tag{1}$$

Where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)

Now if $M$ is larger than $X$ (that is, when the upper bound doesn't matter) we have have that $$c(X,M)=\sum_{j=1}^{X} \binom{X-1}{j-1}=2^{X-1}$$
which counts how many sums there are with $j$ terms, for $j=1$ to $X.$

In that case, our count $(1)$ is:

$$\sum_{d\mid X} \mu(d)\,2^{X/d-1}$$

This sum will have $2^k$ terms, and will require you to know the prime factors of $X.$

In general, though, when $M<X,$ $c(X,M)$ is another inclusion-exclusion count, and you don't get anything quite so nice:

$$c(X,M)=\sum_{j=1}^{X}\sum_{m=0}^{j}(-1)^m\binom{j}{m}\binom{X-Mm-1}{j-1}$$

Now your total in $(1)$ is much harder to compute.